# views.my_login_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

The view accounts.views.my_login_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
here is the code

```
def my_login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
        password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/Skolar/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('<h1>Page was found</h1>')
        else:
            return render(request, "login.html", {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form is not valid there is not response so do the following :

```py
def my_login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
        password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/Skolar/')
            return HttpResponse('<h1>Page was found</h1>')
        return render(request, "login.html", {'form': form})
    return render(request, "login.html", {'form': form})
```

Comment: Better would be to de-indent that last return and remove the `else` so it's just the default if the rest doesn't match. That logic actually requires zero `else` statements :)

Comment: Exactly! Did see that afterwards, updating my answer accordingly, thanks !

Comment: I'm using `def post(self, request, **kwargs):`, how do you solve this?